# ethernet works but wireless does not on Lenovo W520 under Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: wireless

An Ubuntu newbie installed CAELinux 2011 which is based on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS 64bit side-by-side with Windows 7 on Lenovo W520 laptop. Although both ethernet and wireless cards work on Windows 7, they do not on Ubuntu. The cards are Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection and Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205, respectively.

Thanks to sfeole's answer. After upgrading to 10.10 the ethernet works now. But the wireless still does not. Any one can help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The link below talks about the two packages needed to make this work:

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Centrino_Advanced-N_6205

It might be a bit more involved given the discussion on this thread at ubuntuforums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1739047